# Постоянно выполняющиеся func

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Здравствуйте! Надо сделать функцию, которая будет постоянно выполняться, не зависимо от действий пользователя. Есть у меня 4 Action. Из каждого получаю bool значение. Пока решил проблему записью функции в каждый Action, но хотелось бы решить более правильным методом. Так сказать DRY никто не отменял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обьявить таймер с интервалом сколько надо

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("someSelector"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

и запускать метод, какой нравится

```
func someSelector() {
    print("working")
}
```

если надо в какой то момент таймер остановить (тогда таймер надо объвить переменной инстанса)

```
timer.invalidate()
```